# Animate all objects in Google slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm making an automatic slide show of photos, a tale of the year. Each slide (page) in Google slide is an event and each slide/event will have 2-10 photos. Each photo should fade in some seconds after last photo. 
I'm looking for a way to either:

- Set the default animation to fade in, after previous, slow speed. It seems the default now is fade in, at click, fast speed.
- Select all photos in a slide, and give them same object animations
- By Script: Select all photos in the file/slide, or one bye one, and animate them.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is currently not possible.

There is no option in the Slides API (or in any of the services that you can use in Google Apps Scripts, such as [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app) or [Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides)) to interact with items animations.

If you are still interested in the possibility of using such a feature, I suggest you consider creating a feature request in the Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I added it. If anyone else would like this, please up-vote by giving a star: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145770684